# What is the most voted thing on Stack Overflow, and how many votes does it have?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, specific-question, specific-answer

As the title asks, I was curious on the most upvoted thing on Stack Overflow.

I have seen some with 800 upvotes or so but I want to know if there is any question or comment with a seriously outrageous number of votes.

This could be up votes or down votes... I'm just curious.

Comment: Gotta be the [Branch Prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809) one.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes or http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205177/most-upvoted-answers

Comment: If you want to find posts with the most down-votes, you might have trouble finding them, because they tend to get deleted...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That mislays locked posts. Not that that changes the answer any.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Votes vs Score

You need to make a distinction between **number of votes** (both up and down) vs **total net score** (combined score of up minus down votes). You can find total net score easily using on-site tools. If you want to find the highest-*voted* questions and answers, however, you might be able to find that information in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

### Highest Scoring Question

To find the highest scoring question, simply click on the Votes sub-tab for the [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions):

[image: Screenshot]

The highest-scoring question is

- [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

### Highest Scoring Answer

Using the following query in the built-in search:

```
is:answer
```

and then selecting the Votes tab:

[image: Screenshot]

Reveals that the highest-scoring answer on Stack Overflow is

- [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)

which currently has a score of 12,533.

### Lowest Scoring Posts

Using the search query

```
score:..0
```

and selecting the vote tab, and going to the last page:

[image: Screenshot]

reveals that the current un-deleted lowest-scoring question is

- [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

while the lowest scoring un-deleted answer is

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read/278879#278879

with a score of -42.

Comment: If you don't use a search term, you exclude (most?) locked content. `score:any` is a good no-restrict search. Does not really change the picture though.

Comment: those downvoted questions are actually pretty good questions. SE community just doesn't like them. they should have been asked on quora I guess.

Comment: Haha, the 'highest questions' are still flying like mad :)