# What is the most voted up and voted down question and answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

What's the most voted up question and answer in Stack Overflow history?

And what is the most voted down question and answer in Stack Overflow history?

Comment: Note, though, most sites (including SO and meta.SO) like one question per question.

Comment: There's a sort by score thing. Did you try that?

Comment: Most heavily down voted questions and answers end up being deleted

Comment: Related: [Posts with the most conflicting up/down votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382963/5353461) and also

[What is the most voted thing on Stack Overflow, and how many votes does it have?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266568/5353461)

Answer (score 4):

Questions are easy; just change the sort to "votes" - job done:

[image]

Answers are harder; [SEDE would work fine](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490880/highest-lowest-voted-questions-and-answers), though

Comment: For answers, can't you just search for `is:a` and do the same thing?

Comment: @TZHX quite possibly; but I'm a SQL person :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use search and sort by score to find these, but here's a short list:

- The most upvoted question is [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) (14632 votes), and it can be found by searching for [`is:q` and sorting by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq).
- The most downvoted question, (i.e. with the lowest score) is currently [Forcing a function to return if false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068763/forcing-a-function-to-return-if-false), and an honorable mention goes to [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly), which was previously the lowest score question. Both are at ~ -150 votes. These can be found by again searching for [`is:q` and sorting by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq), and going to the last page of the results.

For answers, you can similarly search for [`is:a` and sort by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa), and go to the last page for the most downvoted ones.

- Currently, the highest scoring answer is [Mystical's answer to Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902), currently with a score of 20368.
- The most downvoted answers are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my/4797328#4797328) ("*I solved the problem by dropping the table and restoring it from backup.*"), and [this one to Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator/11155703#11155703), which basically says "Don't do this". (It's also the accepted answer). Both are currently at -58.